# How to catch click on alertify.js notification

Tags: javascript, alertify

I need to catch the click (or hide) event of a alertify.js event. I set up the time to 0 in order to wait to the user for click in the message. Is there any way to attach a function to this event?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="alertify.js-0.3.11/themes/alertify.core.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jalertify.js-0.3.11/themes/alertify.default.css" id="toggleCSS" />
<script src="alertify.js-0.3.11/lib/alertify.min.js"></script>

<script>
    alertify.log('test','',0);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an event to the document, and see if the element clicked on has a class that matches the class names attached to alertify logs (`alertify-log`).

For example, you could use code like this:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if(e.target.className.indexOf('alertify-log') > -1) {
    console.log('Clicked on a log');
  }
}, false);
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/fadaz/1/edit)

Comment: @user3099887 You could distinguish between them using the text `e.target.textContent`. To distinguish them further, you'd probably want to just modify the code to be more flexible to how you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
alertify.log('test',function(){
    //function here
});
```

Comment: Parameters for alertify.log are: alertify.log(message, type, wait). I don't see a callback function but I tried with no luck.

Comment: You probably using http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/ this library. But this library is abandoned so better check fork of this library which is able to let you pass function. https://alertifyjs.org/#notification-callback